# Apache .htaccess URL rewrite adding additional directory in URL path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to build a URL rewrite by adding an additional directory in the URL path; for example, changing;

https://FQDN/mypage/ to https://FQDN/dev/mypage/

https://FQDN/template/ to https://FQDN/dev/template/

I have written the following .htaccess although this is having no affect. I have already enabled a2enmod rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dev/(.+)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @anubhava - simple fix, the rewrite was not activating due to `AllowOverride None` being active in the apache2.conf file. Changing this to `AllowOverride All` allowed the .htaccess file to be active.